# There are 14 students: 8 girls and 6 boys. In how many ways can you make a 4-student committee which has at least one boy?

Tags: combinatorics

In a group of $14$ students there are $8$ girls and $6$ boys. Determine the number of ways that a committee of $4$ students which has at least $1$ boy can be chosen from the group.

Here is what I have so far:

**Method $1$**

If there is $1$ boy: $(^6C_1)\cdot (^8C_3) = 336$

If there are $2$ boys: $(^6C_2)\cdot (^8C_2)= 420$

If there are $3$ boys: $(^6C_3)\cdot (^8C_1) = 160$

If there are $4$ boys: $(^6C_4)\cdot (^8C_0)= 15$

$336+420+160+15 = 931$

I was confident in this answer, until I tried solving another way.

**Method $2$**

number of comittees with at least one boy = total number of committees possible – number of comittees with zero boys

$=(^{14}C_4)\cdot (^8C_8) = 1000$

*Why are my two answers different?*

### EDIT:

Method $2$ should be as follows:

$= (^{14}C_4)-(^8C_4)$

$= 931$

Comment: Shouldn't method 2 be (14C4)-(8C4)?  That might be 1000 and you just made a typo.  I don't have a calculator handy.

Comment: Ah, yes! No, it was my mistake. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @turkeyhundt is right, $\binom{14}{4}-\binom{8}{4}=931$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 2 should be $14\choose 4$-$8\choose 4$.

That will give you 931.

Answer (score 1):

I think in the last step, you wanted to write $^{14}C_4-^8C_8=1000?$ In that case, why $^8C_8?$ From $8$ girls, you are choosing $4$ girls, so you should subtract $^8C_4$. Then you get 931.