# Two combinatorics questions, one on product of combinations, the other on why factoring heuristic isn't applicable

Tags: combinatorics, factoring, prime-factorization

> In a group of $14$ students, there are $8$ girls and $6$ boys. Determine the number of ways that a committee of $4$ students which has at least $1$ boy can be chosen from the group.

Why is the answer $931$ and not ${6 \choose 1 }\cdot { 13 \choose 3}? $

> How many positive integers can be expressed as a product of two or more of the prime numbers $5, 7, 11,$ and $13$ if no one product is to include the same prime factor more than once?

> A. EightB. NineC. TenD. ElevenE. Twelve

---

How does this question have nothing to do with factoring but rather something about combinatorics?

Include one positive integer, positive integer has 2 factors

Include the product of two different positive integers , it has 4 factors

Include product of three, that number has 8 factors

Include product of four, that number has 16 factors.

> " 2) there are two ways for each number - select or not factors. total ways is $2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2 \cdot 2=16$.  Now this includes the $4$ ways when each is taken alone, so subtract $4$ from $16 = 16-4=12$ It also includes the way when none is selected, so subtract $1$. $12-1=11$."

We have to do two or more, so you aren't doing 'each is taken alone.'

I think the answer is $14=16-2$.

https://gmatclub.com/forum/how-many-positive-integers-can-be-expressed-as-a-product-of-two-or-mor-288089.html#p2221462

[There are 14 students: 8 girls and 6 boys. In how many ways can you make a 4-student committee which has at least one boy?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1065841/there-are-14-students-8-girls-and-6-boys-in-how-many-ways-can-you-make-a-4-stu)

Comment: Usually, just ask one question at a time. For 1) you have exactly 1 boy, you need to add the cases where there are 2, 3, or 4 boys. For the second, the fact that you aren't doing 'each is taken alone' is precisely the reason why you must subtract 4 from your total.

Comment: You are counting the case "b1 with b2, g1, g2" and the case "b2 with b1, g1, g2" as separate groupings but they are the same.

Comment: For your second question, try listing the products systematically to see why there are only $11$.  Compare your list to your method of analysis to see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a group of $14$ students, there are $8$ girls and $6$ boys. Determine the number of ways that a committee of $4$ students which has at least $1$ boy can be chosen from the group.

Let's examine two approaches before we address why your suggestion is wrong.

**Method 1:**  We use complementary counting.

There would be $\binom{14}{4}$ ways to select a committee of four students if there were no restrictions.  Of these $\binom{8}{4}$ contain only girls.  Since the committee must contain at least one boy, we subtract the number of committees with only girls from the total number of committees, which yields
$$\binom{14}{4} - \binom{8}{4}$$

**Method 2:** We count directly.

Observe that the number of ways of selecting exactly $k$ of the six boys and $4 - k$ of the eight girls is
$$\binom{6}{k}\binom{8}{4 - k}$$
Since there must be at least one boy on the committee, the number of admissible committees is
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{3} + \binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{2} + \binom{6}{3}\binom{8}{1} + \binom{6}{4}\binom{8}{0}$$

*Why is your method wrong?*

The set of boys and the set of additional people from which you are selecting are not disjoint, so you count each selection with $k$ boys $k$ times, once for each way you could designate one of those $k$ boys as the boy on the committee.  For instance, suppose you choose the boys Adam and Brian and the girls Claire and Denise.   You count this selection twice:

$$
\begin{array}{l l l}
\text{boy} & \text{additional people}\\ \hline
\text{Adam} & \text{Brian, Claire, Denise}\\
\text{Brian} & \text{Adam, Claire, Denise}
\end{array}
$$

Notice that
$$\binom{6}{1}\binom{8}{3} + \color{red}{\binom{2}{1}}\binom{6}{2}\binom{8}{2} + \color{red}{\binom{3}{1}}\binom{6}{3}\binom{8}{1} + \color{red}{\binom{4}{1}}\binom{8}{4}\binom{6}{0} = \color{red}{\binom{6}{1}\binom{13}{3}}$$

> How many positive integers can be expressed as a product of two or more of the prime numbers $5, 7, 11,$ and $13$ if no one product is to include the same prime factor more than once?

**Method 1:**  We count directly.

Since a product must contain two or more of the four prime numbers $5, 7, 11, 13$, it can contain $2$, $3$, or $4$ of those numbers.  Hence, the number of admissible products is
$$\binom{4}{2} + \binom{4}{3} + \binom{4}{4}$$

**Method 2:**  We use complementary counting.

There are $2^4$ possible subsets of four numbers since we must either include or exclude each number from the subset.  Thus, if there were no restrictions, we could form $2^4$ products in which at each number in the set $5, 7, 11, 13$ is used at most once.  However, each product must contain at least two of these four numbers.  Hence, there are
$$2^4 - \binom{4}{0} - \binom{4}{1}$$
admissible products.

Comment: If you include two at least, why do you do $2^4- {4 \choose 1} - {4 \choose 2}$ rather than $2^4- {4 \choose 1}$?

Comment: I meant $2^4 - \binom{4}{0} - \binom{4}{1}$.

Comment: The red-text, is that Vandermonde's identity?

Comment: The red text is used to indicate errors.  The red factors on the left-hand side of the equations are the number of times your proposed method counts each selection with $k \geq 2$ boys, once for each of the $k$ ways you could have designated one of the $k$ boys on the committee as the boy on the committee.  Compare that line with the direct count above it.